# show that $ 4 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-2)^{n+1}\frac{n+2}{n!} $

Tags: power-series

I need to show that $$ 4 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-2)^{n+1}\frac{n+2}{n!} $$

by considering $$ \frac d{dx}(x^2e^{-x})$$

I found that $ \frac d{dx}(x^2e^{-x}) = 2xe^{−x}−x^2e^{−x}$

What would be the next step to show the equality?

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2e^{-x}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+2}}{n!}\implies$$

$$2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(n+2)x^{n+1}}{n!}$$

...and the above is true for **all** $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: To arrive at the answer if I multiply both sides by 2 and put $x=1$ then I am getting answer as $\frac{4}{e}\neq 4$ .Please help

Comment: @learnmore 2*(-1)^n is not (-2)^n

Comment: @learnmore Why would you do such a thing?? Read Tenali's comment above: $$(-1)^nx^{n+1}=x\cdot(-x)^n$$

Comment: so what's the way out @Timbuc

Comment: @learnmore Substitute$\;x=2\;$ and note **your** series begins with $\;n=1\;$

Comment: @Timbuc

$$2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(n+2)x^{n+1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(-x)^n\frac{(n+2)}{n!}$$ and x can be cancelled. But when I plug x=2 the left side becomes 0

Comment: @Togepi **Exactly!!** It becomes zero, and **your** series begins with $\;n=1\;$ and the first summand is $\;4\;$ ....do it!

Comment: @Timbuc I got it thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
It seems that the equality $\frac{n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ for $n\ge 1$ and a shift in the summation index can be used.